# Вставка link Canonical через js

Tags: javascript, html

День добрый! Подскажите, можно ли вставить HTML код на станицу с кодом link Canonical через javascript?

Comment: можно, а в чём смысл?

Comment: Можно привести пример? (Нужно описать Canonical в пагинации только на 1ой странице)

Comment: `var link = document.createElement('link'); link.setAttribute('rel', 'canonical'); link.setAttribute('href', url); document.head.appendChild(link);`

Comment: @norbornen Спасибо! Буду разбираться